# random user sent notice of bug in site, suspect we might have been hacked but unsure

Tags: php, security, code-injection

some random person sent in a message saying there was a bug on our site. They directed us to a specific url within our website which is obviously incorrect.

We haven't clicked on the link and I've checked the server for recent updates to files that I did not make. the only thing I found was one empty text file which a long crazy file name:

MJ12_43CC245DB24A2F895E300CD7F1BAE3E5.txt

the link this person sent to us was something like this (specifics changed for privacy)

http://www.oursite.com/buy.php?category=accessories%22%3C%3E%27%3Cscript%3Ealert%28123%29%3C/script%3E

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a attempted XSS attack.

That URL has the following within it;

```
<script>Alert(123)</script>
```

But it had been URL encoded, if you buy.php script decodes this and displays it on the page without properly sanitizing it, then there will be a popup saying "123".

Please make sure you using the following functions;

```
htmlspecialchars()
```

Or

```
striptags()
```

Always sanitize user inputs!

Comment: thanks for the explanation! This is an old website that was put together before I knew anything about security so it looks like I have some work to do!

Answer (score 0):

Someone sent you a security vulnerability proof. This empty txt file might be related to some penetration tests or not, look for it in the log file of your web server.

On how to handle security vulnerability submission there is a great article on bugcrowd https://blog.bugcrowd.com/security-vulnerability-submission/

And relax, someone just gave you a gift :)